# The Data Bound ComboBox doesn't update until the application is restarted

Tags: c#, combobox

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cons))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Dealers (DealerId,DealerName) values (NEXT VALUE FOR Dealers_DealerId_SEQ,@dname)", con))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dname", this.ComboText.Text.ToString());
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

This Code updates the table that provides data to the combox. It updates the database well but not the application dropdown untill the application is restarted. Any help will be appreciated.

```
this.Dealers.DataSource = this.dealersBindingSource; this.Dealers.DisplayMember = "DealerName"; this.Dealers.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; this.Dealers.Name = "Dealers"; this.Dealers.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21); this.Dealers.ValueMember = "DealerName";
```

this is the code that has anything to do with the combobox.

Comment: There is no UI code here.  Since the UI is what isn't behaving as you'd like, you should post some of the UI code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload the combobox.

Suppose you use this method to fill combobox

```
public void LoadCb()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select DealerId, DealterName from Dealers", cn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DealerName";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "DealerId";
}
```

then you have to Call LoadCb method after inserting the values in your dealers table

Comment: Either .Net is too dumb or I'm too smart for it,you have to take care of things it should by itself obvoisuly.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown above does only update the database. I don't know how your data source looks, but in any case you will have to re-assign it to your drop-down control.

If your data source is a `List<T>` then either add the new item to the list at the same time as to the database or reload the list from the database. If you re-assign the very same list to `DataSource` you will have to assign `null` to `DataSource` before, otherwise the drop-down will not notice the change.

You could also use a `BindingList`. Changes to the `BindingList` will automatically update the drop-down.

If the data source is a dataset, you will have to requery the dataset, i.e. you will have to re-read the data from the database.